# How to trigger multiple Click events on one click angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am having different ng-clicks events, I want all those to be triggered at once on click of a button

Example

```
 <div ng-controller="one">
   <input type="button" id="one" ng-click="firstBtnClick(a,b)" class="fstClass"/>
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="two">
   <input type="button" id="two" ng-click="SecBtnClick(c,d)" class="SecClass"/>
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="three">
   <input type="button" id="three" ng-click="ThirdBtnClick(e,f)" class="ThirdClass"/>
 </div>
```

Now I want to hit all this click functions on other button

```
<div ng-controller="final">
 <input type="button" id="final" ng-click="finalBtnClick" class="FinalClass"/>
</div>
```

Final Controller code

```
$timeout(function () {
 angular.element('.fstClass', '.SecClass').triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

But I am unable to achieve, Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are in the same controller you can chain together like this:

```
<input type="button" id="final" ng-click="firstBtnClick+SecBtnClick+ThirdBtnClick" class="FinalClass"/>
```

For communication across controllers you can create and inject a shared service to each controller, nest controllers, use $rootscope or use $emit:

```
function FirstController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$on('clickFirst', function(event, args) {
       firstBtnClick(args)//click first button
   });
  // another controller or even directive
}

function FinalController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$emit('clickFirst', args);
}
```

Comment: Each click is in Different controllers and there are different parameters on each click function??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this in the view? You are calling controller functions with every button click.

> So just have a `ng-click="everyClick()"` and inside this controller
>   function, call every function you want to call.

So:

```
$scope.finalBtnClick = function() {
 $scope.firstBtnClick();
 $scope.SecBtnClick();
 $scope.ThirdBtnClick();
}
```

Comment: Different controllers so unable to call those

Comment: Each click is in different controller and there are different parameters on each click function